# Drupal 7 Multicolor Menu

Tags: css, drupal, drop-down-menu, menu, drupal-7

I want to have horizontal menu, e.g. 4 buttons/links in 4 different bgcolor with their respective siblings in the same color: e.g. 1st menu item in RED and with its siblings in red, 2nd one in GREEN and siblings in green, 3rd one in black and black siblings and 4th one in yellow and yellow siblings. the parent level menu will be of fixed width. 2nd levels may differ.. allowing line breaks/auto wrapping etc.

any suggestion on multicolor menu, please?

Thank you

e.g. img http://www.cssmenusamples.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/wakestock.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If your parent menus have unique ids or classes you can do it with css ([example](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/parent-menu-and-sub-menu-background-color/)).

If your theme/module does not print unique ids/classes you can add them with [theme_menu_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) function or with module [menu_attributes](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional CSS.

li a { border: 5px solid #FFFFFF; }

li:first-child a{ background-color: #000000; }

li:first-child + li > a{ background-color: #0000FF; }

li:first-child + li +li > a{ background-color: #00FFFF; }

li:first-child + li +li +li > a{ background-color: #00FF00; }

Change the color codes as you like..Hope this will be helpful to you.